# Error when using mlogit package version 1.1-0. dfidx::dfidx providing id2 is irrelevant

Tags: r, mlogit

The following is a minimum working example that generates the error. The following code worked in previous versions of mlogit but no longer works in version 1.1-0 (released May 26, 2020).

```r
library(mlogit)
data("ModeCanada", package = "mlogit")
bususers <- with(ModeCanada, case[choice == 1 & alt == "bus"]) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, ! case %in% bususers) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, noalt == 4) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, alt != "bus") 
ModeCanada$alt <- ModeCanada$alt[drop = TRUE] 
KoppWen00 <- mlogit.data(ModeCanada, shape='long', 
    chid.var = 'case',alt.var = 'alt', choice = 'choice',            
    drop.index = TRUE, varying = 5:8)
```

Upon executing the last line of code above the following error is generated: `Error in dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index = dfa#drop.index for data in wide format, providing id2 is irrelevant.` This error message is confusing in two ways. First, the code seems to be misinterpreting my data; the data is in long format (this is example "long" data that comes with the `mlogit` package and works into several of their examples) and I pass the function the argument "long", but the error says the data is being interpreted as  "wide" and that is causing a problem. The second part of the error message tells me that `id2` is irrelevant, but I don't know what `id2` is; a search of the `mlogit` vignettes and package description for `id2` yielded no results.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be introduced with the way `dfidx` is handling (or receiving) the data. By default, `mlogit.data` (which is a wrapper for `dfidx` in the most recent version of the `mlogit` package) is able to find the "varying" columns when the data is in long format. For example, with data on transportation choice, if individual i is choosing over transportation options j = 1, .., J, dfidx can tell that columns 5 through 8 are properties of the different transportation choices j (e.g. the cost of taking a car, train or bus) and not properties of the individual i (cf income in column 9 of `ModeCanada`, which is not "varying"). Thus, it seems when the "varying" argument is passed to `mlogit.data`, it forces the function to interpret the data as though it were in the "wide" format, despite even the user passing the function the argument "shape = long".

The solution is just to remove the argument "varying" from the function `mlogit.data` in this case, since mlogit.data can now determine the varying columns for itself when you pass it data in long format. That is, the following code will accomplish your goal.

```r
library(mlogit)
data("ModeCanada", package = "mlogit")
bususers <- with(ModeCanada, case[choice == 1 & alt == "bus"]) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, ! case %in% bususers) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, noalt == 4) 
ModeCanada <- subset(ModeCanada, alt != "bus") 
ModeCanada$alt <- ModeCanada$alt[drop = TRUE] 
KoppWen00 <- mlogit.data(ModeCanada, shape='long', 
    chid.var = 'case',alt.var = 'alt', choice = 'choice',            
    drop.index = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry just saw you answer as I posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

From the `mlogit.data` help page: "mlogit.data is deprecated, use dfidx::dfidx() instead". So I think `mlogit.data` calls `dfidx`. There the `varying` argument causes the error, because if this argument is set, `dfdix` assumes the data is in wide format.